# How to add Video calling feature with ionic4

Tags: video, ionic4, angular8, videocall

Hello developers i want a pro tips or suggestion to implement video calling feature in ionic 4,5 app. Kindly suggest me the best way for ionic4,5 thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey You can try the following

1.Simple Peer which is a WebRtc Based Communication you can try that as a Communication Medium / Use Socket Client to Consume Streams from the server and can use Camera- Capacitor Plugin to Create the Stream and send to the server via socket

2.For Server side you can have a Node Server Which Can Perform the Routing of Streams to Various Clients through socket.io for Subscription Management.

I am Making an open-source project for the same purpose here is the link https://github.com/omkar-dev/IONIC-VideoCall-Template it would take me a weeks time to close the same you can refer to it if you want

Comment: Thanx a lot i will try this.